# HTML being stripped/replaced by redactor on initialising despite being saved correctly

Tags: redactor

When i enter HTML into redactor below it will strip out the first closing div and the second opening div leaving one col-md-6.  It actually saves it as I have below but as soon as redactor is re-initialised it strips out the closing and opening tag in the middle again.  This means no one can ever go in an edit the content as it will be a single column again once saved. Current setup of redactor is below and I have unchecked the clean HTML.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>One Col</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>One Col</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Redactor JSON config:

```
{
        buttons: ['html','formatting','bold','italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image','video'],
        plugins: ['fullscreen'],
        toolbarFixedBox: true,
        replaceDivs: false
        replaceDivs: false,
        paragraphize: false,
        removeEmpty: ['strong', 'em', 'span', 'p']
    }
```

Any ideas how I can get it just to accept the HTML we enter without problems?

Comment: Hi Andy, this doesn't answer your question but is something to consider; having 'complex' markup like this in a Rich Text field may not be the best idea, it might be worth considering a Matrix field (depending on the context here): http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields or another Craft field that handles purely the content, and the column markup is defined in your templates.

Comment: Thansk for responding Jamie but this is actually a matrix field :(  Its quite annoying!

Comment: You mean the RTE is inside of a Matrix field? What Jamie is suggesting is ditching the RTE altogether and solely use a Matrix field. You'll have much more control over the markup, then.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the `allowedTags` attribute in your Redactor config?

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    allowedTags: ['div','p', 'h1', 'h2', 'pre']
});
```

You can read about that here:

http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-allowedTags

Answer (score 3):

Add `replaceDivs: false` only once in your JSON config and do not forget ***the comma*** at the end of each settings row.

Answer (score 2):

For me adding `replaceDivs: false` in redactor config file fixed my issue on div tag removal.